# Altering logging level for some logger

Tags: .net, log4net

I am using logging using log4net in my application and it works fine.

One of the libraries I use (NHibernate) uses log4net too and I'd like to log its messages too, but I want to log them with a different level. So, if the library logs something with the level `ERROR`, I want the message to appear in my log with the level `WARN`, because I don't consider those to be errors.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it: you can't.

What you could do is loge the nhibernate errors to a different appender so they won't show up in your 'normal' log where errors go. You would get something like this:

```
<root>
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="NormalLogAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="NHibernate">
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateLogAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Yeah, I realize I could do that, but I want them in a specific appender (a `UdpAppender` that shows in our logging application).